# Holoviews change datashader colormap

Tags: python, colormap, holoviews, datashader

I'm trying to change the colormap used by datashader.

I tried this:

`datashade(scatter, cmap='Reds')`

Where `scatter` is an `hv.Scatter` element. This doesn't work because datashader expects an iterable or a function that returns colors. As such, this works:

`datashade(scatter, cmap=['blue'])`

So how can I take the `'Reds'` colormap and convert it into something datashader can use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right; you can't pass the string name of a colormap to Datashader's `cmap` argument, because Datashader interprets a single string as the name of a single color, constructing a colormap from it by setting the R,G,B channels to that color and then varying the alpha channel. If you want a colormap, either pass a list of colors (as used by Bokeh for its palettes) or a Matplotlib colormap object (not the string name) to `cmap`:

```
from matplotlib import cm
datashade(scatter, cmap=cm.Reds)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I know Seaborn also provides this type of colormaps, and i think that Bokeh does the same. Any way i can access the colormaps here: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Colormaps.html

Comment: for bokeh you can do: from bokeh.palettes import Magma256; datashade(scatter, cmap=Magma256) Available bokeh palettes can be found here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html#large-palettes

Answer (score 1):

To choose from any colormap available to Holoviews, use the following code:

```py
from holoviews.plotting.util import process_cmap

datashade(scatter, cmap=process_cmap("Magma", provider="bokeh"))
```

Change `"Magma"` and `"Bokeh"` to [any of the supported colormaps](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Colormaps.html) (Thanks to @Chris for the link).

---

Request: It would be nice if `opts` parameters given to Holoviews plots were automatically transferred if `datashade` supports them, as requested by this GitHub issue: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4125.

Answer (score 1):

You can also **use library [hvplot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/)** which is **built on top of HoloViews** to create your plots, use datashader and change the color mapping, all in a convenient way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.normal(size=100000),
    'y': np.random.normal(size=100000),
})

# use keyword datashade=True to turn on datashading
# use keyword cmap to change the default colormap
df.hvplot.scatter(
    x='x', 
    y='y', 
    datashade=True, 
    cmap='Magma',
)
```

**Colormaps can be found here:**
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Colormaps.html

**Resulting plot:**
[image: using hvplot to change datashader color mapping]